# Calendar date pick gets saved as wrong format in JSON

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG for the calendar. I've formatted the date as shown on their website, but when the date/time gets saved to the backend it saves as:

```
2017-09-22T06:11:54.000Z
```

I want it to save as 21/07/2017 12:00:00 AM

This my template code:

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date7" formControlName="startdatetime" [showTime]="true" [hourFormat]="12" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy"></p-calendar>
```

This is my component file:

```
date7: Date;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use datePipe, to formate date.
`import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(public datePipe:DatePipe)

let formatedDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.date7, 'dd/MM/y jms');`